# Can this analog speed regulation for a DC motor be used for this scenario?

Tags: motor, analog, dc, speed

I’m dealing with a part of a small project where a device’s(DUT in the diagram) rotor is rotated at a desired fixed/constant rotational speed for a while and slows down itself by disengaging the speeding mechanism.

A small PM DC motor(M below) is used to provide rotation to the device. So when the switch SW is ON, the motor shaft in a way couples to the device’s rotor and brings it to a constant speed. The device also outputs freq. proportional to its rotation speed. So this freq. channel is monitored via a scope and logged by a data acquisition hardware DAQ. So after engaging the motor to the device, by playing the motor voltage Vs I fine tune the rotation speed to a fixed value, lets say 40Hz. After a while of constant coupling and rotation speed I turn OFF the switch and the device slows down. Basically this way I measure the friction of the device bearings but that is not related to electrical part. Below is the illustration:

[image]

Now the thing is, the temperature of the closed system in yellow above is varied from room temperature down to subzero. So the test is made at different temperatures to find the temperature effect on bearings.

I have noticed that even Vs is constant, the motor speed varies like 3 to 5Hz at low temperatures and as far as I found out, coupling at different results different load on the motor; the friction increases and I have to fine tune the freq. by varying the Vs knob at each step.

I think I can live with 1Hz variation. First I thought to use PID with a microcontroller but the motor might jerk and maybe it is hard for me to achieve an overkill. For me the power consumption does not matter and was looking for something analog. And I need a fixed freq. maybe set by a pot. I have come across the following circuit example [here](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Interface/cmscontrol.htm). Can this circuit be used for slight load variations for a fixed rotational speed each time the motor is coupled to the device? I couldn’t come up with another simple solution.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a motor that you can actually *set* to an exact speed rather than needing a control loop to *correct* it. What type of motor is this? I'd argue this sounds like a DC / universal motor, whereas your best bet would be an asynchronous motor with an AC source of defined frequency.

Comment: Yes exactly it looks like a DC motor like this https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/283616958916 Vs is less than 12V DC in my diagram. My drawing is out of proportion in size.

Comment: And yes exact speed rather than a controlling loop.

Comment: 12 V is due to being battery-powered, I presume. Otherwise, an synchronous AC motor for grid voltage would produce stable rotational speed. What you can do is use a bipolar stepper motor (cheap!), and drive it more like a synchronous AC motor with two 90°-shifted sines; I'd assume you could generate these sines with a simple stereo audio amplifier, that you feed with e.g. these two sines, coming from a CD player or some microcontroller or PC or raspberry pi or...

Comment: Vs is a variable power supply. What u suggest is more complicated and I will have hard time to convince others to make such change in setup. But the circuit in link do you think it would not work? http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Interface/cmscontrol.htm

Comment: That circuit is bad because it uses a controllable current source – whereas for constant load, the speed of a DC motor is proportional to the voltage, not the current. Also, not convinced that a BD139 is sufficient to drive your motor; there's easily 2A passing through your motor! Again, a simple DC motor is the wrong type of motor for this job.

Answer (score 0):

That circuit depends on indirectly measuring the back-EMF of the motor and servoing it to a constant by (again, indirectly) compensating for the motor's winding and commutator resistance.

But the motor's speed vs. back-EMF "constant" is not constant with temperature, nor is the winding resistance.

So you may get *better* regulation over temperature, but I don't think you'll get tremendously good regulation.

I'd recommend that you measure the speed and wrap it with a PID.  If you tune it conservatively you won't see a "jerk", although you may have to wait for it to stabilize.

Comment: Not part of your question, but -- as the voltage/speed constant of the motor changes so does the torque/current constant.  So if you're measuring the motor's current as a way of determining torque, that is also going to be subject to errors due to temperature.  If I were doing this experiment, I'd have the motor on some sort of a torque balance so that I know the motor torque independently.

Comment: If you want to reduce the speed variation from 3-5 out of 40 Hz t0 1 out of 40 Hz, I think a PID regulation of measured speed with the existing motor should do the job with either analog or PWM voltage control. There should also be quite a wade latitude of workable PID or PI implementation methods.

Answer (score 0):

This job calls for anything *but* a DC motor like the one you're using.

Look into brushless DC motors (BLDC), especially from the automation and from the RC (toy) car and quadcopter markets; these are internally actually synchronous motors, and typically have a "speed control" input with which you can actually set the rotational speed that they run at. The integrated controls of that motor make sure it runs at the speed you set. Done!

For example, from a [BLDC motor datasheet](https://www.alliedmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/documents/E75s_3_Datasheet_R1scrn.pdf), a typical cabling:

[image: BLDC cable]

You'd only need to connect Black and Red to your power source, and yellow to anything that gives a voltage between 0 and 10V to *set* the speed.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot find analog speed controlled BLCD Im restricted with farnell and rs at the moment. I find such things https://uk.farnell.com/maxon-motor/203892/motor-13mmdia-15vdc-1-2w/dp/1761300

Comment: it says "DC motor with brushes". my first sentence is literally "anything *but* a DC motor". So, no. Please search for "BLDC" on farnell yourself! THere's at least 11 motors.

Comment: They have min rpm as 100 or 200. But I guess this could be fixed by a gear system for lower rotations.